# ERROR 1878 (HY000): Temporary file write failure in mysql

Tags: mysql, alter

When i am running Alter command in mysql to add a new column to my existing table. I am facing this error.

```
ERROR 1878 (HY000): Temporary file write failure.
```

Any idea regarding this? Please guide.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Mysql will recreate the file. make sure that you have enough space.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502633/error-1878-hy000-temporary-file-write-failure

Comment: MySQL server machine's hard drive full? temp space full?

Comment: How can I increase the space allocated to /tmp for mysql?

Answer (score 7):

This error is most likely resulting from the temporary directory MySQL is using being too small (as others mention in the comments). In many cases altering a table in MySQL will result in the table being duplicated and you will need at least as much free space in the temporary directory as is used by the table being altered.

The destination for the temporary directory is specified in the `my.cnf` file under the variable `tmpdir`. The `my.cnf` is usually stored in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on Ubuntu for example (not sure what OS you are using). You can either change the location the `tmpdir` variable points toward (to another larger partition), or alter the size available to the directory specified.

On Ubuntu, for example, you can use `df -h` to see the sizes of the various filesystems available.

Answer (score 0):

Find more detailed logs under `/DATA/mysql/<log-file-name>.err` (find the right path with `show variables like 'log%';`)