# Mysql RDS with 3 million records not allowing to add new column

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-rds

Hi I have mysql rds database server and one of my table is having `3 million+` records when I am trying to add new column it's always failing and giving following error

Query `ALTER TABLE user_notifications ADD program_id int(11);`

Error   `Temporary file write failure`.

My RDS DB instance is `db.t2.medium`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1878 (HY000): Temporary file write failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502633/error-1878-hy000-temporary-file-write-failure)

Comment: Always search for the error code for better and quicker answers. Also, post error code(if any) when posting the question.

Answer (score 2):

`ALTER TABLE` is a table re-creation, so two copies of the table will exist on the system at some stage during the process.

So, you will need free space more than `data length` size for this operation.

You can check `data length` in table info.

There is this [alternate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25503284/923426), in which you create a new table with new desired schema, and move data from old table to new table in chunks.

Comment: "ALTER TABLE is a table re-creation, ... at some stage during the process. " Not always true MySQL 5.6+ supports online DDL on InnoDB tables ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html )..  "Specifying ALGORITHM=INPLACE makes the operation use the in-place technique for clauses and storage engines that support it, and fail with an error otherwise, thus avoiding a lengthy table copy if you try altering a table that uses a different storage engine than you expect. " source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will re-create the table when using an alter so you need enough free space on the disk for another copy of the table.

I suspect the table is large as it has 3million records and your disk does not have sufficient space

[This article](https://makandracards.com/makandra/39413-mysql-mariadb-show-disk-usage-of-tables-and-columns) shows how to determine how much disk space a tables are using

Comment: "MySQL will re-create the table when using an alter ... disk for another copy of the table." Not always true MySQL 5.6+ supports online DDL on InnoDB tables ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html )..  "Specifying ALGORITHM=INPLACE makes the operation use the in-place technique for clauses and storage engines that support it, and fail with an error otherwise, thus avoiding a lengthy table copy if you try altering a table that uses a different storage engine than you expect. " source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html